# IF field in MS Word referring to another cells

Tags: if-statement, ms-word, field

Good day,

I'm trying to make an IF formula in Microsoft Word within a field, but for some reason I cannot get the cell reference working, as shown on the example below:

[image]

The result I'm getting is wrong:

[image]

What I would like to achieve in Word, in Excel would look like this:

[image]

Can you help me figuring out what's wrong? It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's three ways:

```
{=A1>B1 \# "'Yes';;'No'"}

{=A1-B1 \# "'Yes';'No';'No'"}

{IF{=A1}>{=B1} "Yes" "No"}
```

To see how to do a wide range of other calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html
or:
http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Comment: Thank you very much. Solution 1 and 2 are indeed working, but the 3rd one with the IF is not working for me. Can you please verify if it should be exactly the spacing as you provided and if this is working for you?

Comment: All three work for me. Note that *all* the field braces (i.e. {}) must be created by Ctrl-F9 - they can't be typed or copied from here.