# Can you create an "input field" in Microsoft Word to use in an "If field"

Tags: if-statement, input, ms-word

I am attempting to create an If statement in a Word document that uses the value of the field with the "name" bookmark to determine whether it should say "Hello Alex" (True) or "What is your name" (False)

Is it possible to have the person viewing the Word document fill out a field on the document to update the If statement? Do the variables have to come from a third party site?

Here is the "If field" field code I am using:

`{ IF "{{name}}" = Alex "Hello Alex" "What is your name?"\* MERGEFORMAT }`

I have attempted to use a legacy text form field with the bookmark "name" but this does not update the if statement. I have attempted to an "Ask" field and this also hasn't worked.

There is a post regarding table cells ([IF field in MS Word referring to another cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303162/if-field-in-ms-word-referring-to-another-cells)) but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this from an input field.

Comment: There are  a number of ways. One is the Ask Field. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AskField. The superior method though is likely a UserForm which is far more flexible and powerful. http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userForm.html See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/some-fields-are-updated-while-other-fields-are-not-eb3ad53a-328b-a3b4-91c6-28a84001855f and my article on Dealing with Fields https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the variables do not have to come from a third party site.

Your question has some ambiguities, but if you have a Word bookmark named "NAME", then

```
{ IF "{ NAME }" = "Alex" "Hello Alex" "What is your name?" }
```

would display the text `Alex` if the bookmark's value was `Alex`, and would display `What is your name?` If it was not `Alex`. But it would not generate an input box or any other structure that would let you enter a name.

In this case, you could also use

```
{ IF NAME = "Alex" "Hello Alex" "What is your name?" }
```

You could also do this

```
{ IF NAME = Alex "Hello Alex" "What is your name?" }
```

but be aware that that may not work as you expect if you happen to have something like

```
{ SET NAME Alex }{ SET Alex Alx }{ IF NAME = Alex "Hello Alex" "What is your name?" }
```

*All* the {} pairs have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows Desktop Word using ctrl-F9, on Mac Desktop Word using cmd-F9, or a varietion on those sequences depending on your keyboard and setup.

At the moment you appear to have doubled up whatever type of brace you are using

```
{ IF "{{name}}" etc.
```

That won't work!

The value of the bookmark NAME could come from a number of place. e.g. you might select a piece of text and insert the bookmark "NAME" there, e.g. if I selected `piece of text` and inserted a bookmark called NAME, the value of NAME would be `piece of text`. Or you could set the value of NAME using

```
{ SET NAME "piece of text" }
```

Or you could use an ASK field like this

```
{ ASK NAME "What is your name?" }
```

or a combination of a SET and a FILLIN field (Let's not go there). You (or the user) has to select all the relevant fields and "update" them (e.g. F9 on Windows Word).

In addition, if your document is a mailmerge main document connected to a data source that has a column called NAME, you *may* find that the data in that column is used to populate a bookmark in Word called NAME. This dates back to early versions of Word where you referenced a column in the data source using { NAME } rather than { MERGEFIELD NAME }. I think that in recent versions it only applies to data sources that Word opens through its file converters, e.g. if the data source is a Word document or HTML file, not (say) an Excel workbook opened using OLE DB.

And you can of course try to set the name using something like

```
{ IF "{ NAME }" = "Alex" "Hello Alex" "{ ASK NAME "What is your name?" }" }
```

but the user would have to execute that `IF` field twice to see `Hello Alex` if the value of bookmark `NAME` was not `Alex` beforehand. It doesn't seem like a very good approach. Nor is there a looping construct in Word that would help you there.

When choosing bookmark names,

- avoid names that are the names of Word field types (such as `IF`, `ASK`, `FILLIN`, `SET` etc.
- avoid names that "look like" table cell names (`A1`, `AB1` etc.)

The other possible way to do this would be to use "legacy Form Field codes, and use a Textbox field to enter the name. That type of textbox field also has an associated bookmark name that you can specify in the field's properties. But to use those legacy form fields, you have to put the whole document into "protected for forms" mode, which means that everything else becomes uneditable.